# Event for monitoring add/remove MovieClips from display list?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip, let's call it "myMC", that is very long (5,000 frames) over the course of which many dozens of nested movieclips are added/removed as children to/from "myMC".

**Without reference to the nested clips**, is there a way I can add a listener to myMC and listen for when an object is added/removed from it (something along the lines of Event.ADDED)?

Answer (score 4):

`Event.ADDED` and `Event.REMOVED` will help you out.

Thise events are [bubbling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#bubbles), so it's not necessary to listen to immediate parent. You can catch these events in any display ancestor, like the example below shows.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var onAdded:Function = function (event:Event) : void
{
    // event.target references the display object being added
    trace(event.type +": '" + event.target.name+"'");
}

var onRemoved:Function = function (event:Event) : void
{
    // event.target references the display object being removed
    trace(event.type+": '" + event.target.name+"'");
}

addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded);
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, onRemoved);

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.name = 'Container here'
addChild(container);

var test:Sprite = new Sprite();
test.name = "I am the one!";
container.addChild(test);
container.removeChild(test);

/*
added: 'Container here'
added: 'I am the one!'
removed: 'I am the one!'
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Just add an event listener for `Event.ADDED` to your parent `MovieClip`. When children are added, the `ADDED` events will bubble up and invoke your handler. You can read the `event.target` property from your handler to retrieve the particular child instances.

Comment: Wrong, event.target won't contain your recently added movieclip.

Comment: @Artemix, are you sure? The official documentation states that this should be the case: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED